# Comparing date values in VBA

Tags: vba

I have a simple code below and I can't find the error why it gives incorrect value.
The MSgbox should show "Within SLA" but it shows the other result.

```
If Format(12 / 28 / 2019, "mm/dd/yyyy") < format(Date,"mm/dd/yyyy") Then
    MsgBox "WITHIN SLA"
Else
    MsgBox "OUTSIDE SLA"
end if
```

Comment: `Format` returns a `Variant/String`. You don't want to do a `<` comparison with strings.

Comment: That is not a date. That is division. `If CVDate("12/28/2019") < Date Then`

Comment: @BigBen Im trying to compare two dates, any suggestion how can I convert this values to date?

Comment: @braX already gave you the answer :-)

Comment: yes, I noticed. Thanks All.